# Weird exploit messing with email

Tags: php, email, exploit

Found a weird hack today someone was exploiting,
was wondering how this arbitary code could execute thousands of emails an hour.

http://pastebin.com/m7nBSmfB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing weird about the code you posted --  it builds up a PHP function in an obfuscated fashion -- then it calls the generated code.

The real problem/issue is, how is your server being made to *run* this code? If you have indeed been exploited by this, it's because you're allowing them to run arbitrary PHP code on your server.

You need to figure out how *that* happened.

Comment: It does use a Joomla build that is likely out-dated. Thanks for that, so the code itself is just php built to hide the details?

Having removed the joomla build it has ceased. 

The code itself, why does it appear there are arrays after the hex?

Comment: There is no hex, there is a string consisting of seemingly strange characters, which is the "alphabet" that this script uses to produce other strings (that is what you are seeing where the "arrays" are).  For example, the first string to be created contains "error_reporting".  I would be worried about HOW that file got on your server.

Comment: $x74[10].$x74[60].$x74[60].$x74[84].$x74[60].$x74[35].$x74[60].$x74[10].$x74[39].$x74[84].$x74[60].$x74[72].$x74[81].$x74[11].$x74[71]

I do notice this does come out to "error reporting" 60's being r's.
Yes, definitely have our security team on it now figuring out the how/who/when behind this now.